# Unity Generate waypoints list from a svg stroke?

Tags: unity-game-engine, svg, path, vector-graphics

I have some simple stroke drawings (e.g.  circle, loop shape…) exported as svg file. I'm able to import the svg into Unity as Vector Sprite. Now I want to generate a list of waypoints based on that svg so that I can manipulate another game object moving along the path. How can I achieve this in Unity? Any thoughts?

Answer (score 0):

I didn't worked with imported SVG, but I assume you'll get a path consists of points, each with document-space coordinates, so is this any problem to just get those coordinates and reconstruct points in world-space? Seems like an obvious solution. The concrete form of implementation is highly depends on your object's movement system, which is not highlighted in your question. But hey, this is a freedom of programming at the end - you can manipulate the data however you like!

Comment: My main problem is I did not find a solution to get the coordinates data from the import drawings. I just think SVG will work but I’m still finding out. Do you have any idea?